# Rails 3.1: Could not find generator foundation:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, zurb-foundation

Rails is unable to find the generator foundation:install.  It is very strange.

Attempting to run the foundation:install generator:

```
macbook$ rails g foundation:install
Could not find generator foundation:install.
```

Listing the available generators:  `macbook$ rails g --help`

```
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  mailer
  migration
  model
  observer
  performance_test
  plugin
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  session_migration

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:devise

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Devise:
  devise
  devise:install
  devise:views

FactoryGirl:
  factory_girl:model

Gmaps4rails:
  gmaps4rails:install

Jquery:
  jquery:install

Js:
  js:assets

Mongoid:
  mongoid:devise

NestedForm:
  nested_form:install

Rspec:
  rspec:install

TestUnit:
  test_unit:controller
  test_unit:helper
  test_unit:integration
  test_unit:mailer
  test_unit:model
  test_unit:observer
  test_unit:performance
  test_unit:plugin
  test_unit:scaffold
```

Huh.  No Foundation listed.

Previously I had added 'zurb-foundation' to my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
gem 'rake', '10.0.3'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'gmaps4rails', '1.4.8'
gem 'devise'
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'timezone'

gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
    gem 'rb-fsevent'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :assets do
    gem 'sass', '>= 3.2.0'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '> 4.0.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then I ran `bundle install`:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using multi_json (1.7.9) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using activemodel (3.1.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.10) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.3.7) 
Using sprockets (2.0.4) 
Using actionpack (3.1.1) 
Using mime-types (1.24) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.3.3) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.1) 
Using arel (2.2.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.1.1) 
Using ansi (1.4.3) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using xpath (2.0.0) 
Using capybara (2.1.0) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using debugger-linecache (1.2.0) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3) 
Using debugger (1.6.1) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.3) 
Using devise (2.2.7) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.4) 
Using factory_girl (4.2.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) 
Using ffi (1.9.0) 
Using formatador (0.2.4) 
Using gmaps4rails (1.4.8) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.3) 
Using rb-inotify (0.9.1) 
Using rb-kqueue (0.2.0) 
Using listen (1.3.0) 
Using lumberjack (1.0.4) 
Using method_source (0.8.2) 
Using slop (3.4.6) 
Using pry (0.9.12.2) 
Using guard (1.8.2) 
Using rspec-core (2.14.5) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.14.2) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.14.3) 
Using rspec (2.14.1) 
Using guard-rspec (3.0.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using nested_form (0.3.2) 
Using rails (3.1.1) 
Using rspec-rails (2.14.0) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.7) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8) 
Using timezone (0.2.1) 
Using turn (0.9.6) 
Using uglifier (2.2.0) 
Using zurb-foundation (4.3.1) 
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./devise
```

And my Gemfile.lock looks like this:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    ansi (1.4.3)
    arel (2.2.3)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    debugger (1.6.1)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.3)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)
    devise (2.2.7)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    gmaps4rails (1.4.8)
      json
    guard (1.8.2)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 1.0.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (3.0.2)
      guard (>= 1.8)
      rspec (~> 2.13)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    listen (1.3.0)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.24)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    multi_json (1.7.9)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.3.10)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.1)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.14.1)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.5)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    sass (3.2.10)
    sass-rails (3.1.7)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    slop (3.4.6)
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    timezone (0.2.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turn (0.9.6)
      ansi
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    zurb-foundation (4.3.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara
  coffee-rails (>= 3.1.1)
  debugger
  devise
  factory_girl_rails
  gmaps4rails (= 1.4.8)
  guard-rspec
  jquery-rails
  nested_form
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  rake (= 10.0.3)
  rb-fsevent
  rspec-rails
  sass (>= 3.2.0)
  sass-rails (>= 3.1.4)
  sqlite3
  timezone
  turn
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  zurb-foundation (> 4.0.0)
```

I've tried redoing it from scratch with the same results.

Totally stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  Solved.  Problem of my own making.

I have RVM on this machine.  In my .rvmrc file, I was forcing Rails to version 3.1.1 which was messing with bundler and breaking things.  Clear that file, problems evaporate.

*smacks head*